# paint() method would not draw on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, draw, drawing2d

I tried few source codes of drawing in java and they were working fine, but when i tried to make one of my own I could not get the `paint(Grahpics g)` method to work! I looked again at the codes I have and checked some of the tutorials in Oracle's pages but i don't seem to be able to know why it would not work.
can someone please check it and tell me what is wrong here??

main method:
public class main

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new board();
    }
}
```

board:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class board implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Speedy");
    private JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();


    private Image bg = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("road.png")).getImage();
    private Timer t;


    private car myCar = new car();


    public board()
    {
        t = new Timer(50,this);
        t.start();


        gamePanel.setSize(600,400);
        gamePanel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        gamePanel.setFocusable(true);
        gamePanel.addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(gamePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //f.addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        f.setBounds(200,100,600,400);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.revalidate();
        f.repaint();

    }




    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        gamePanel.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
        g2d.drawImage(myCar.getImg(), myCar.xPos, myCar.yPos, null);

        System.out.println("Painted");

        g.dispose();
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        gamePanel.repaint();
        //System.out.println("Painting..");
    }





    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  
        {
            myCar.keyPressed(e);
            System.out.println("You pressed: "+e);
        }
    }

}
```

car.java:

```
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon

;



public class car 
{

    private Image image;
    public int xPos,yPos;

    public car()
    {
        image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("car.png")).getImage();
        xPos = 300;
        yPos = 200;
        System.out.println(image.getWidth(null));
    }



    public Image getImg() {return image;}


    public void move() {}


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) xPos -= 1;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)xPos += 1;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)   yPos -= 1;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) yPos += 1;
    }

}
```

There are no errors, it shows me the width of the image which is right, also the timer triggers the `ActionListener`, also `KeyListener` is working, but the images would not draw! the `paint(Graphics g)` method just does not want to get triggered!
Googling it did not help.. I thought this would be a common problem but nobody has the problem I have, all solutions failed me.
help please?
If someone can explain it would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Board` does not extend the `JPanel` class. So the `paint()` method is never called by the Swing. 
Also, the statement `gamePanel.repaint()` will only execute the default `JPanel` `paint()` method of `gamePanel`. Instead you want the overridden `paint` method to be executed, so might want to do this:

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   ....
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       this.paint(g);

       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
       g2d.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
       g2d.drawImage(myCar.getImg(), myCar.xPos, myCar.yPos, null);

       System.out.println("Painted");

       g2d.dispose();
    }
    ....
}
```

Replace your action functionality with this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   this.repaint();
}
```

**Alternative solution:**
If you do not want your `Board` class to extend `JPanel`, you can also override the `paint()` method of the `gamePanel` as you initialize it.

```
gamePanel = new JPanel() {
   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
       this.paint(g);

       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
       g2d.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
       g2d.drawImage(myCar.getImg(), myCar.xPos, myCar.yPos, null);

       g2d.dispose();
   }
};
```

However, I would recommend the first solution rather than this one with [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: but i did `gamePanel.repaint()`, shouldn't that trigger it? can't i trigger it onto the current JPanel?

Comment: No, `gamePanel` is an instance of a `JPanel`, calling `gamePanel.repaint()` is only going to trigger the original `JPanel` `paint()` method. However, you want to trigger **your** `paint` method which has the implementation of drawing a car. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to set the current paint method for the new instance of the JPanel in the current code? or do i have to create a new object of it?

Comment: also, based on what you are saying the `paint(Graphics g)` method is actually an override of the original `JPanel` object?

Comment: Yes, you could override the `paint` method of the `gamePanel` when you initialize it. Regarding your second question, the `paint` method is supposed override the default `paint` method in order to extend the default functionality.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I'd give you a +1 but not enough reputation yet :(  thank you very much, it makes more sense now

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `repaint` on some container, then what happens is that Swing looks at all the components in that container and calls their `paint` method.

However, your `board` class (you should be calling it `Board`, by the way. Class names should always start with a capital) is not a component of your JFrame. When you call `repaint`, Swing will attempt to call the paint method of the `JPanel` that is a component of that `JFrame`. But you didn't override that method. You just added a `paint` method to your `board`, and `board` is not a component of the `JFrame`.

For this reason, usually you are supposed to create a class that extnds `JPanel` or some other component, and then add the current object of that class as a component to the JFrame. This way, your `paint` method will be called when the `JFrame` is repainted.

Answer (score 0):

Your "main" class (`board`) should extend JPanel to work as expected.
With your way, `paint` would never be called. it acts like any normal self-written function.

If you want to keep things as they are, you can do something ike that:

```
gamePanel = new JPanel() 
{
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        //your code here
    }
};
```

Please keep in mind that a `Class` name should start with a capital letter. It won't make any errors but it is a naming convention as you can see here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html